# Windows Server 2016, all installers and lots of services stop working until restart

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer, installer

Been dealing with this problem for a while on our Windows Server 2016 Standard server, not virtual.

Frequently (but not limited to):

- All installations for software stop working
- Sage backups stop running
- Windows Defender signature updates stop working
- Windows stops checking for updates
- Scheduled Windows backups are not completed

Only thing in the error log of relevance is error code 1603, which seems to be a general error.

```
Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: Sage MTD for VAT. Product Version: 1.0.0.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Sage UK Limited. Installation success or error status: 1603.
```

The only thing that appears to fix it is restarting the whole server, which in a production environment is not at all a good solution.  Even then, the symptoms start reappearing within a week and everything stops working again.

So far I have:

- Restarted installer service, unregistered, re registered multiple times
- Changed the short names registry entry to 0
- Completed multiple Microsoft Fixit applications
- Manually updated Defender with the manual installer download, which did complete successfully
- Cleared all temp folders
- Permissions on C: drive set to SYSTEM full control

Tried enabling logging on the installer I'm trying at the moment and this is what I get, nothing obvious:

```
=== Logging started: 16/12/2019  11:45:30 ===
Action 11:45:30: INSTALL. 
Action start 11:45:30: INSTALL.
Action 11:45:30: CommonFilesFolder.0FCB48C5_2430_4EE6_8BE7_5D3F1FCF7422. 
Action start 11:45:30: CommonFilesFolder.0FCB48C5_2430_4EE6_8BE7_5D3F1FCF7422.
Action ended 11:45:30: CommonFilesFolder.0FCB48C5_2430_4EE6_8BE7_5D3F1FCF7422. Return value 1.
Action 11:45:30: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
Action start 11:45:30: FindRelatedProducts.
Action ended 11:45:30: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
Action 11:45:30: AppSearch. Searching for installed applications
Action start 11:45:30: AppSearch.
AppSearch: Property: NETFRAMEWORK452, Signature: NETFRAMEWORK452
Action ended 11:45:30: AppSearch. Return value 1.
Action 11:45:30: LaunchConditions. Evaluating launch conditions
Action start 11:45:30: LaunchConditions.
Action ended 11:45:30: LaunchConditions. Return value 1.
Action 11:45:30: ValidateProductID. 
Action start 11:45:30: ValidateProductID.
Action ended 11:45:30: ValidateProductID. Return value 1.
Action 11:45:30: CostInitialize. Computing space requirements
Action start 11:45:30: CostInitialize.
Action ended 11:45:30: CostInitialize. Return value 1.
Action 11:45:30: FileCost. Computing space requirements
Action start 11:45:30: FileCost.
Action ended 11:45:30: FileCost. Return value 1.
Action 11:45:30: CostFinalize. Computing space requirements
Action start 11:45:30: CostFinalize.
Action ended 11:45:31: CostFinalize. Return value 1.
Action 11:45:31: MigrateFeatureStates. Migrating feature states from related applications
Action start 11:45:31: MigrateFeatureStates.
Action ended 11:45:31: MigrateFeatureStates. Return value 0.
Action 11:45:31: WelcomeDlg. 
Action start 11:45:31: WelcomeDlg.
Info 2898.For Font_Normal textstyle, the system created a 'Tahoma' font, in 1 character set, of 13 pixels height.
Action 11:45:31: WelcomeDlg. Dialog created
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control Title on dialog LicenseAgreementDlg extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 20 pixels
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are: LicenseAgreementDlg, Title, to the right
Action 11:45:32: LicenseAgreementDlg. Dialog created
Action 11:45:34: VerifyReadyDlg. Dialog created
Action ended 11:45:37: WelcomeDlg. Return value 1.
Action 11:45:37: ProgressDlg. 
Action start 11:45:37: ProgressDlg.
Info 2898.For Font_Title textstyle, the system created a 'Tahoma' font, in 1 character set, of 13 pixels height.
Action 11:45:37: ProgressDlg. Dialog created
Action ended 11:45:37: ProgressDlg. Return value 1.
Action 11:45:37: ExecuteAction. 
Action start 11:45:37: ExecuteAction.
Action ended 11:45:37: ExecuteAction. Return value 3.
Action 11:45:37: FatalError. 
Action start 11:45:37: FatalError.
Action 11:45:37: FatalError. Dialog created
Action ended 11:45:38: FatalError. Return value 2.
Action ended 11:45:38: INSTALL. Return value 3.
Property(C): UpgradeCode = {A631EEE7-AFAF-4AFC-BFF6-48E306BE9DBB}
Property(C): NETFRAMEWORK452 = #528049
Property(C): LicenseAccepted = 1
Property(C): DesktopFolder = C:\Users\administrator.EXAMPLE\Desktop\
Property(C): ApplicationProgramsFolder = C:\Users\administrator.EXAMPLE\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Sage MTD for VAT\
Property(C): dir25A241B53537CCB8AD6107CAAAD8873B = C:\Program Files (x86)\Sage\Sage MTD for VAT\Plugin\
Property(C): SageMTDBridge = C:\Program Files (x86)\Sage\Sage MTD for VAT\
Property(C): ErrorDialog = ErrorDialog
Property(C): TARGETDIR = E:\
Property(C): ProgramMenuFolder = C:\Users\administrator.EXAMPLE\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\
Property(C): SystemFolder = C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
Property(C): Sage = C:\Program Files (x86)\Sage\
Property(C): ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\
Property(C): SourceDir = C:\Users\administrator.EXAMPLE\Downloads\
Property(C): Privileged = 1
Property(C): ARPPRODUCTICON = IconMtd.ico
Property(C): ARPNOREPAIR = 1
Property(C): ARPNOMODIFY = 1
Property(C): DefaultUIFont = Font_Normal
Property(C): Manufacturer = Sage UK Limited
Property(C): ProductCode = {6F238AC4-DFD6-44BB-B79F-D25DDC6C32D2}
Property(C): ProductLanguage = 1033
Property(C): ProductName = Sage MTD for VAT
Property(C): ProductVersion = 1.0.0.0
Property(C): SecureCustomProperties = WIX_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED;WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED
Property(C): WixPdbPath = G:\Dev\Sage 200\MTD-Main-Prod\Sources\Master\Bin\Install\Standalone\en-GB\SageMTDforVAT.wixpdb
Property(C): MergeRedirectFolder.0FCB48C5_2430_4EE6_8BE7_5D3F1FCF7422 = C:\Program Files (x86)\Sage\Sage MTD for VAT\
Property(C): AutoUpdateManager.0FCB48C5_2430_4EE6_8BE7_5D3F1FCF7422 = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Sage\Shared\AutoUpdateManager\
Property(C): AutoUpdateManagerVersionDir.0FCB48C5_2430_4EE6_8BE7_5D3F1FCF7422 = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Sage\Shared\AutoUpdateManager\v2\
Property(C): Shared.0FCB48C5_2430_4EE6_8BE7_5D3F1FCF7422 = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Sage\Shared\
Property(C): Sage.0FCB48C5_2430_4EE6_8BE7_5D3F1FCF7422 = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Sage\
Property(C): CommonFilesFolder.0FCB48C5_2430_4EE6_8BE7_5D3F1FCF7422 = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\
Property(C): VersionNT = 603
Property(C): MsiLogFileLocation = C:\installlog.log
Property(C): PackageCode = {B28DD062-35C3-4C45-9078-12E2FDBEE68C}
Property(C): ProductState = -1
Property(C): PackagecodeChanging = 1
Property(C): REBOOT = ReallySuppress
Property(C): CURRENTDIRECTORY = C:\Users\administrator.EXAMPLE\Downloads
Property(C): CLIENTUILEVEL = 0
Property(C): CLIENTPROCESSID = 20112
Property(C): MsiSystemRebootPending = 1
Property(C): VersionDatabase = 300
Property(C): VersionMsi = 5.00
Property(C): VersionNT64 = 603
Property(C): WindowsBuild = 9600
Property(C): ServicePackLevel = 0
Property(C): ServicePackLevelMinor = 0
Property(C): MsiNTProductType = 2
Property(C): WindowsFolder = C:\Windows\
Property(C): WindowsVolume = C:\
Property(C): System64Folder = C:\Windows\system32\
Property(C): RemoteAdminTS = 1
Property(C): TempFolder = C:\Users\ADMINI~1.RIG\AppData\Local\Temp\
Property(C): CommonFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\
Property(C): ProgramFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\
Property(C): CommonFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\Common Files\
Property(C): AppDataFolder = C:\Users\administrator.EXAMPLE\AppData\Roaming\
Property(C): FavoritesFolder = C:\Users\administrator.EXAMPLE\Favorites\
Property(C): NetHoodFolder = C:\Users\administrator.EXAMPLE\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\
Property(C): PersonalFolder = C:\Users\administrator.EXAMPLE\Documents\
Property(C): PrintHoodFolder = C:\Users\administrator.EXAMPLE\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts\
Property(C): RecentFolder = C:\Users\administrator.EXAMPLE\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\
Property(C): SendToFolder = C:\Users\administrator.EXAMPLE\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\
Property(C): TemplateFolder = C:\Users\administrator.EXAMPLE\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\
Property(C): CommonAppDataFolder = C:\ProgramData\
Property(C): LocalAppDataFolder = C:\Users\administrator.EXAMPLE\AppData\Local\
Property(C): MyPicturesFolder = C:\Users\administrator.EXAMPLE\Pictures\
Property(C): AdminToolsFolder = C:\Users\administrator.EXAMPLE\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\
Property(C): StartupFolder = C:\Users\administrator.EXAMPLE\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
Property(C): StartMenuFolder = C:\Users\administrator.EXAMPLE\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\
Property(C): FontsFolder = C:\Windows\Fonts\
Property(C): GPTSupport = 1
Property(C): OLEAdvtSupport = 1
Property(C): ShellAdvtSupport = 1
Property(C): MsiAMD64 = 6
Property(C): Msix64 = 6
Property(C): Intel = 6
Property(C): PhysicalMemory = 32672
Property(C): VirtualMemory = 7088
Property(C): AdminUser = 1
Property(C): MsiTrueAdminUser = 1
Property(C): LogonUser = administrator
Property(C): UserSID = S-1-5-21-3170842105-3658024141-1870963093-500
Property(C): UserLanguageID = 2057
Property(C): ComputerName = RIGI-DC
Property(C): SystemLanguageID = 2057
Property(C): ScreenX = 1600
Property(C): ScreenY = 900
Property(C): CaptionHeight = 23
Property(C): BorderTop = 1
Property(C): BorderSide = 1
Property(C): TextHeight = 16
Property(C): TextInternalLeading = 3
Property(C): ColorBits = 32
Property(C): TTCSupport = 1
Property(C): Time = 11:45:38
Property(C): Date = 16/12/2019
Property(C): MsiNetAssemblySupport = 4.8.3761.0
Property(C): MsiWin32AssemblySupport = 6.3.14393.0
Property(C): RedirectedDllSupport = 2
Property(C): MsiRunningElevated = 1
Property(C): DATABASE = C:\Users\administrator.EXAMPLE\Downloads\SageMTDforVAT.msi
Property(C): OriginalDatabase = C:\Users\administrator.EXAMPLE\Downloads\SageMTDforVAT.msi
Property(C): SOURCEDIR = C:\Users\administrator.EXAMPLE\Downloads\
Property(C): VersionHandler = 5.00
Property(C): UILevel = 5
Property(C): ACTION = INSTALL
Property(C): EXECUTEACTION = INSTALL
Property(C): ROOTDRIVE = E:\
Property(C): CostingComplete = 1
Property(C): OutOfDiskSpace = 0
Property(C): OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0
Property(C): PrimaryVolumeSpaceAvailable = 0
Property(C): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRequired = 0
Property(C): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRemaining = 0
Property(C): INSTALLLEVEL = 1
=== Logging stopped: 16/12/2019  11:45:38 ===
MSI (c) (90:54) [11:45:38:889]: Product: Sage MTD for VAT -- Installation failed.

MSI (c) (90:54) [11:45:38:889]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: Sage MTD for VAT. Product Version: 1.0.0.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Sage UK Limited. Installation success or error status: 1603.
```

Would be massively appreciative of any advice, causing me a lot of headaches!

Comment: Could you include the content of the error you found?

Comment: @Burgi Have just included it near the top, it's pretty generic and the same for all installers

Comment: Is there anything in the EventViewer that matches up with this?

Comment: @Burgi Only one that says `Product: Sage MTD for VAT -- Installation failed.` with no additional information, event ID 11708

Comment: Based on the information provided the problem is Sage. What have you done to address the problem with Sage? Have you talked to the vendor?

Comment: @Appleoddity The problem occurs with all installations of any product, anything from printer drivers, to CCleaner, .NET installations and MS Office, sometimes the installer will say it was "interrupted" but the error code is always 1603.  Effectively nothing can be installed until it can be rebooted safely on the following weekend, nightmare

Comment: A stuck installation will cause future installation problems. It appears Sage is trying to install an update and fails. I don’t see sufficient information to eliminate this as the source of the problem. This, from the info provided, is the only thing happening on a regular schedule. All of this looks like an MSI issue. Do the first installer to experience a problem is likely the cause of all problems.

Comment: Sage (Accounts service) has only been installed for about two months, trust me Sage is not the issue as it's been happening for over a year.  Windows Updates and Backups also stop working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unbelievably this turned out to be the print spooler causing this multitude of issues.  **Restarting the print spooler fixes all the issues mentioned.**  I cannot fully explain all the headaches this has caused me over the past year.

Windows backups stopped working, all installers stopped working, server could not add/remove roles...  I even fixed every single error that occurred in the event log and still every 3–4 days the server would just stop functioning in these ways.

I am still looking into the exact cause of the issue (as I've only just found this out) but for now I can just restart the service when it happens.  I found this reported "fix" here:  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6f728e8f-86ce-44f2-8694-6b36b2c644df/dism-error-during-server-manager-refresh?forum=ws2016

The error that led me there was:

`The Deployment provider failed to initialize DISM. Error: 0x80070008`